# how to send Message using MI command in opensips

Tags: opensips

Salam, I searched the internet many times to find the MI Command (Datagram or FIFO) to send a message to a SIP user, even that it is mentioned so in the opensips documentation.

Any one can help please?

Comment: It seems to be done through t_uac_dlg. In trying to figure out how.

Answer (score 2):

I found it and I'll post it hear, it might be useful for someone else.

sudo opensipsctl fifo t_uac_dlg MESSAGE "sip:+962790000000@zajil.no-ip.org" . . "\"From: sip:+962796638484@zajil.no-ip.org\r\nTo: sip:+962790000000@zajil.no-ip.org\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\n"\" 123456